# Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined - form errors

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, error-handling, backend

I'm creating a simple book-discussion forum page as my final school project. I'm using only HTML, Javascript and CSS. I'm a bit new to back-end, and just set up a Cloud Database in Google Firebase. I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVz47tr7vv0 and trying to connect the input forms to the database. However, I think the methods used in the tutorial are in Firebase version 8.2.1, while I'm using version 9.14.0. See code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="form_card">
            <form id="submit_form">
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <input type="text" id="title" required="required" autocomplete="off">
                    <span>Title</span>
                </div>

                <div class="inputBox">
                    <input type="text" id="review" required="required" autocomplete="off">
                    <span>Review</span>

                    <button type="submit" id="post_btn"><p>POST</p></button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        
        <script src="form.js" type="module"></script>

        <script type="module">
            // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
            import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-app.js";
            // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
            // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
            // Your web app's Firebase configuration
            const firebaseConfig = {
              apiKey: "AIzaSyB7ZiJKzHTsgJ3sv8QsOHPLnWCqqnGSSJ0",
              authDomain: "litary-project.firebaseapp.com",
              projectId: "litary-project",
              storageBucket: "litary-project.appspot.com",
              messagingSenderId: "147018135042",
              appId: "1:147018135042:web:eb4d3d5e9dcb79d89bd91b"
            };
          
            // Initialize Firebase
            const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
            const db = firebase.firestore();    //I GET ERROR HERE

        </script>
```

Javascript:

```
//Code
var titleVal = document.getElementById('title');
var reviewVal = document.getElementById('review');

const btn = document.getElementById('post_btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function handleClick(e) { //Listen to click
  
    e.preventDefault();

    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#title, #review');
    
      console.log(titleVal.value);
      console.log(reviewVal.value);

    inputs.forEach(input =>{
      input.value = '';
    });
});
```

I've initialized firebase into my HTML code as said in the Firebase setup, but as soon as I try to call firebase, (ex. `firebase.firestore();` ) I get this error in Edge Inspector:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined.`
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Import firebase before Your script. If Your script is imported first, it cannot know what firebase is since it ran Your code before firebase is even imported.

Comment: Still doesnt work :(